# Find the inverse of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

Let
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
n & n_1 & n_2 & \cdots & n_s & 0 \\
n_1 & n_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1  \\
n_2 & 0 & n_2 & \cdots & 0 & 1 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
n_s & 0 & 0 & \cdots & n_s & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $n=\sum_{i=1}^sn_i$.

My questions: What is $A^{-1}$? Does it have an elegant expression?

My attempts: I tried some small matrices and found that $A^{-1}$ has the following form:
$$
A^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & -\frac{1}{s} \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \frac{1}{s}  \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \frac{1}{s} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \frac{1}{s} \\
-\frac{1}{s} & \frac{1}{s} & \frac{1}{s} & \cdots & \frac{1}{s} & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

While I faild to find patterns in those "dots" parts.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If all the $n_i$'s are $0$, the matrix is not invertible.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe, thanks for the comment. But my interest lies in when $n_i$ are all positive numbers, or more specifically, positive integers. I suppose in this case, $A$ is invertible?

Comment: I suspect that a nice approach would be to compute the inverse of the submatrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
n & n_1 & n_2 & \cdots & n_s  \\
n_1 & n_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0   \\
n_2 & 0 & n_2 & \cdots & 0  \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots  \\
n_s & 0 & 0 & \cdots & n_s 
\end{bmatrix},
$$
then compute the full inverse using the Woodbury matrix identity

Comment: Actually, it turns out that this submatrix is never invertible, which makes my suggestion problematic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Partial Answer:** Here's a strategy you might find helpful.

Let $M$ denote the submatrix of $A$ given by
$$
M = \pmatrix{n & n_1 & n_2 & \cdots & n_s  \\
n_1 & n_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0   \\
n_2 & 0 & n_2 & \cdots & 0  \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots  \\
n_s & 0 & 0 & \cdots & n_s}.
$$
we see that $M$ can be expressed in the form
$$
M = \sum_{i=1}^s (e_1 + e_{1+i})(e_1 + e_{1+i})^T,
$$
where $e_1,e_2,\dots,e_{s+1}$ denotes the canonical basis of $\Bbb R^n$. This gives us the decomposition $M = BDB^T$, where
$$
B = \pmatrix{e_1 + e_2 & e_1 + e_3 & \cdots & e_1 + e_{s+1}} = 
\pmatrix{1&1&\cdots&1\\1\\&1\\ && \ddots \\&&&1},
\quad D = \pmatrix{n_1 \\ & \ddots \\ && n_s}.
$$
So, the matrix $A$ can be written in the form
$$
A = \pmatrix{BDB^T & x\\ x^T & 0},
$$
where $x = (0,1,1,\dots,1)^T$.

Let $C$ denote the matrix
$$
C = \pmatrix{1&-1&\cdots & -1\\
&1\\
&&\ddots\\
&&&1}.
$$
We note that
$$
CB = \pmatrix{0\\&I_{s}}.
$$
With that in mind, we find that
$$
\tilde C A \tilde C ^T = \overbrace{\pmatrix{C&0\\0 & 1}}^{\tilde C} \pmatrix{BDB^T & x\\ x^T & 0} \pmatrix{C&0\\0 & 1}^T = 
\pmatrix{D & Cx\\ (Cx)^T & 0}.
$$
It would suffice to find the inverse of this "nicer" matrix $\tilde C A \tilde C ^T$, then compute
$$
A^{-1} = \tilde C^T[\tilde C A \tilde C ^T]^{-1}\tilde C.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the hint, which is very helpful! But I suppose there are a few typos? For example, $B$ should be a $s+1$ by $s$ matrix, here column $e_1+e_{s+1}$ is missing. Besides, $CB$ should be $s+1$ by $s$ matrix with a zero vector as its first row and $I_s$ as  the other part. As a result, the upper left corner of $\tilde{C}A\tilde{C}^T$ should be a $s+1$ by $s+1$ diagonal matrix with $0, n_1, \dots, n_s$ as its diagonal elements.

Comment: @Chris Yes, that's all correct. I wasn't too careful when typing this up; sorry for any confusion